# "Looking for connected device" Error when interfacing via I2C to BBB

Tags: javascript, beagleboneblack, i2c

I am trying to print a message to an [OLED screen](http://www.adafruit.com/products/326), everytime a button is pushed. Whenever I try running the code, I receive this "error". Im not sure what is causing it, or how I can resolve it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    var b = require('bonescript');

    var button = "P8_12";
    b.pinMode(button, b.INPUT);

    var five = require('johnny-five');
    var board = new five.Board();
    var oled = require('oled-js');
    var font = require('oled-font-5x7');

    b.attachInterrupt(button, true, b.CHANGE, printTime)

    function printTime(x) {
        if(x.value == 1){
            var d = new Date();
            board.on('ready', function() {

                var opts = {
                    width: 128,
                    height: 64,
                    address: 0x3c
                };

                var oled = new Oled(board, five, opts);
                oled.setCursor(1, 1);
                oled.writeString(font, 1, 'Button Pushed At:' +d, 1, true);
            });
        }
        else{
            var d = new Date();
            board.on('ready', function() {

                var opts = {
                    width: 128,
                    height: 64,
                    address: 0x3c
                };

                var oled = new Oled(board, five, opts);
                oled.setCursor(1, 1);
                oled.writeString(font, 1, 'Button Released At:' +d, 1, true);
            });
        }
    }
```

EDIT: This is the output when I run

root@beaglebone:~# i2cdetect -r -y 1

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 3c -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- UU UU UU UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

And this is the output when I try to run my program.

```
1428684567492 Looking for connected device
```

I've double checked my wiring, and I believe that it is all correct, so Im not really sure what is causing the problem.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: It just says  "1428684567492 Looking for connected device."

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/ajfisher/node-pixel/issues/68