# Grove Seeed Studio sensors not working properly with Intel Edison

Tags: hardware, intel-xdk, intel-edison

I've been trying to run simple scripts on my Intel Edison to try the different Grove Seeed Studio sensors and cannot manage to make them work.

My board is configured correctly, its firmware is up to date, and all cables have been connected correctly as shown on different tutorials. I can connect to the board through the IDE, via SSH, and with serial.

I've been using mainly the templates provided by the Intel-XDK IDE because I'd like to develop using javascript and nodejs. The "Onboard LED Blink" template has worked perfectly. My board successfully blinked the onboard LED light so the board is clearly listening to my machine, but all the other templates have failed to make my sensors work. For example, running the "Local Temperature" template which aims to just retrieve the local temperature with the temperature sensor, just prints `Sample Reading Grove Kit Temperature Sensor` and stays there without printing any temperatures in the console. This has been the case for other sensors and other templates like the "Touch Notifier" template which when running also just prints `Sample Reading Touch Sensor` and performs no other actions when touching the touch sensor.

I tried moving away from the Intel XDK templates and trying some of Johnny-Five templates like [this one](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/blob/master/docs/grove-lcd-rgb-temperature-display-edison.md) and still no success. After running that particular script the console just printed `Looking for connected device`. I found a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562688/looking-for-connected-device-error-when-interfacing-via-i2c-to-bbb) but nobody was able to solve the issue.

It almost seems as if I am not being able to properly connect to the sensors. I get no errors on the console, just not the desired outcome. What am I doing wrong? How can I even debug this?

Comment: I got this to work, not sure why this works and the others dont: https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/blob/master/docs/grove-lcd-rgb-temperature-display-edison.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The samples in the XDK are at first glance a bit deceiving. The "Local Temperature" and "Touch Notifier" are designed to work with HTML5 companion apps on a phone for example (you can see this by reading the template description when you select it). Hench when you see the xdk printing the message out, it is first listening for a connection to the HTML5 app which is where it will send the temperature for display. There is an article about the "Local Temperature" app that goes into further detail and how to set everything up here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/creating-a-temperature-monitoring-app-using-intel-xdk-iot-edition

And if you want code for individual sensors, I recommend using this link here to search for code by sensor (each one should have code for c++, javascript, and python code samples): https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/hardware/sensors

Comment: makes sense!~ dang now all the socket stuff in the code makes sense. Thank you so much!